# Where is the breakpoint code located in the React export from Anima?

Tags: reactjs, breakpoints

I followed the steps to add breakpoints using [Anima](https://docs.animaapp.com/v3/figma/prototype/breakpoints.html)'s Figma plugin and SHIFT-selecting the three desktop, tablet, and mobile frames. Then I clicked "save" and synced with my Anima account.

After extracting the exported zip file, I cannot find the breakpoints in `styleguide.css`, `globals.css`, or by searching the entire project in VS Code for keywords "media" (as in media queries,) or "breakpoints."

Posting in the Anima forums and lastly, opening a support ticket, have not yielded any results so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anima's plugin does not generate media queries or values which could be used in Material UI or Bootstrap -- it only generates CSS dimensions of elements exported from Figma.